# Fill the color of polygons with some attribute value using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, symbology, fields-attributes

I have a large set of polygon features where I need to add some attribute value in "Name"  field. Because it is a large set of polygons I want to have all polygons where I have add the value to be filled with some color and the empty ones to be uncolored. I am using ArcGIS 10.4. I have tried to create some new "Status"  field depending on "Name" field with value 0 for unpopulated polygons and value 1 for populated polygons. On that way I can set the symbology by "Status"  field. But I don't have idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click the layer and go to properties (aka Layer Properties)
2. On the left side of the symbology tab change from the default 'Single symbol' to 'Categories'
3. Choose the 'Name' field from the Value Field dropdown
4. Click 'Add Values' and add the value of `<Null>`
5. Change colors as you wish by simply clicking on the color
6. Click OK